# binding click to div to toggle checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am trying to bind a click event to a div to toggle a checkbox thats inside of it. I tryed this:

```
$(".extraOp").bind('click', function(){
        var chk = $(this).find('input');
        chk.attr('checked', !chk.attr('checked'))
    });
```

The problem is that it only works one time, check and uncheck and then nothing. Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr)

```
chk.prop('checked', !chk.prop('checked'))
```

or

```
chk.prop('checked', function(i, checked){
    return !checked
})
```

Read [Prop vs Attr](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc)